# Getting contents by jQuery closest

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I've problem with using jQuery's `closest()`. When I want to print an example, like the `d` variable, I get undefined error.

```js
$(".eb").click(function() {
  var d = $(this).closest(".contact-info");
  var t = $(this).closest(".contact-tell");
  var n = $(this).closest(".contact-name");
  var i = $(this).closest(".contact-id");
  console.log(d.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="contact-id">
      <?php echo $value[0]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="contact-name">
      <?php echo $value[1]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="contact-tell">
      <?php echo $value[2]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="contact-info">
      <?php echo $value[3]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <a href="?IDD=<?php echo $value[0]." &owner=".$_SESSION['username'];?>">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) = *traversing up through its ancestors*, but the elements you are searching are siblings of the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) only looks at ancestors. `.contact-info` is not an ancestor of `.eb`.

Look for the closest `tr` (the nearest common ancestor) then search within:

```
var d=$(this).closest("tr").find(".contact-info")
```

A slightly more efficient way...

```js
$(".eb").click(function() {
  var $ancestor = $(this).closest("tr"); // Cache 'tr' so we don't have to look it up every time
  var d = $ancestor.find(".contact-info");
  var t = $ancestor.find(".contact-tell");
  var n = $ancestor.find(".contact-name");
  var i = $ancestor.find(".contact-id");
  console.log(d.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="contact-id">
      echo $value[0];
    </td>
    <td class="contact-name">
     echo $value[1];
    </td>
    <td class="contact-tell">
      echo $value[2];
    </td>
    <td class="contact-info">
      echo $value[3];
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
        BUTTON
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your advice looks to be the solution but again I'm getting "Undefined" error with this:var d=$(this).closest(".tr").find(".contact-info");

Comment: It should be `tr` not `.tr`. You are looking for a table row not a class.

Comment: Why user is forced to accept just one answer! Thank you ! All answers are helpful and solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach could be traversing to the [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and select the [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```js
$(".eb").click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  var d = $parent.siblings(".contact-info");
  var t = $parent.siblings(".contact-tell");
  var n = $parent.siblings(".contact-name");
  var i = $parent.siblings(".contact-id");
  console.log(d.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="contact-id">
      Id
    </td>
    <td class="contact-name">
      Name
    </td>
    <td class="contact-tell">
      Tell
    </td>
    <td class="contact-info">
      Info
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <a href="?IDD=<?php echo $value[0]." &owner=".$_SESSION['username'];?>">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
       Click me!
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `closest()` looks directly up the DOM tree, and the elements you're searching for are not parents of the `.eb` element; they are siblings of it's grandparent. To fix this use `closest()` to get a common ancestor, then `find()`. Try this:

```js
$(".eb").click(function() {
var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var d = $row.find(".contact-info");
  var t = $row.find(".contact-tell");
  var n = $row.find(".contact-name");
  var i = $row.find(".contact-id");
  
  console.log(d.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="contact-id">
      contact-id
    </td>
    <td class="contact-name">
    contact-name
    </td>
    <td class="contact-tell">
    contact-tell
    </td>
    <td class="contact-info">
    contact-info
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <a href="?IDD=<?php echo $value[0]." &owner=".$_SESSION['username'];?>">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</i>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery functions then you should use variable as jQuery object as below

```
 var i = $parent.siblings(".contact-id");
  console.log($(d).html());
```